# Wronskian of $x|x|$ and $x^2$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

Wikipedia says wronskian of $x|x|$ and $x^2$ is identically zero.
But it is not LD.

I know why these two are LI and not LD.

since x|x| is not differentiable function,how to find their wronskian????
 And plz suggest ways to check LI and LD when functions are not differentiable.

Thanks in advance.
Plz help.

Comment: What means LI  and LD?

Comment: linearly independent and linearly dependent  @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: $x \mapsto x \vert x \vert$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(x)=x|x|$ is is differentiable everywhere.  For $x>0$, you have $f(x)=x^2$, differentiable. For $x<0$ you have $f(x)=-x^2$, differentiable. At $0$, you have 
$$
\frac{f(h)-f(0)}h=\frac{h|h|}h=|h|\to0, 
$$
so the derivative exists and is zero.

For two functions, using the Wronskian is overkill. Linear dependence for two functions means that one is a multiple of the other: this is trivial to check for yes or for no. In your example, for instance, if $x|x|=cx^2$ for all $x$, then evaluate at $1$ to get $c=1$, and at $-1$ to get $c=-1$; so such $c$ cannot exist and the functions are linearly independent.

Comment: What about linear Independence of |x| and x? (Here, |x| is not differentiable at x=0) and what to do for other non-differentiable functions???

Comment: Exactly what I said applies: if $|x|=cx$, evaluate at any positive $x$ and you get $c=1$; evaluate at any $x<0$ and you get $c=-1$.